# Concatenating Pandas DataFrames with mis-aligned indexes

Tags: pandas, concatenation

I have 3 dataframes, `train` and `test` contain my train and test sets respectively. `svd_col` contains features for both the train set and test set, in that order.

**The dimensions line up:**

```
print(svd_col.shape)
print(train.shape)
print(test.shape)

#output:
(237774, 32) # 32 SVD components
(225609, 45)
(12165, 2) # 225609 + 12165 = 237774 as expected
```

Now, I want to concatenate the SVD values with the `id` and `target` columns of my train set, and with the `id` column of my test set.

**It works as expected for the train set:**

```
X_train = train[['id', 'target']]
print(X_train.shape)
print(svd_col[0:len(X_train)].shape)
X_train = pd.concat([X_train, svd_col[0:len(X_train)]], axis=1)
print('X_train', X_train.shape)

# output:
(225609, 2)
(225609, 32)
X_train (225609, 34) # perfect!
```

**Now the problem! I want to do the same for the test set:**

```
X_test = test[['id']]
print(X_test.shape)
print(svd_col[len(X_train):].shape)
X_test = pd.concat([X_test, svd_col[len(X_train):]], axis=1)
print('X_test', X_test.shape)

# output:
(12165, 1)
(12165, 32)
X_test (24330, 33) # why 24330 and not 12165?!
```

I guess the problem is that the index of `svd_col` doesn't start at 0, so I tried to reset it:

```
X_test = X_test
X_test = pd.concat([X_test, svd_col[len(X_train):].reset_index()], axis=1)
print('X_test', X_test.shape)

# output:
(12165, 1)
(12165, 32)
X_test (12165, 34) # why 34 and not 33?
```

**But now I have an extra "index" column that I'm unable to drop :-/**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is after `reset_index` is created new column from index.

You need parameter `drop=True` for avoid it:

```
X_test = pd.concat([X_test, svd_col[len(X_train):].reset_index(drop=True)], axis=1)
```